# How to unset fee rate after setting with RPC `settxfee`

Tags: transaction-fees, json-rpc

After setting the fee rate with `settxfee` -- how do I re-allow bitcoind to set the fee automatically again? Or does the `settxfee` command only apply to the *next* outgoing transaction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/476cb35551f559573c81a3927856b3f76aecd6e9/src/wallet/fees.cpp#L54) suggests that `settxfee 0` should return you to the automatic fee setting.  However this behavior is undocumented and there is a TODO suggesting that it might go away in the future.  Otherwise, you can restart bitcoind.